# PHP upload script doesn't upload .swf files?

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm having some trouble figuring out why my upload script won't upload .SWF, but will upload .JPG .GIF etc.

Is there some setting in PHP.ini which blocks the upload of flash files to a folder?

If anyone could help me out I'd be very happy.

Here is the script.

```
<?php

    include('init.php');

    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["gameToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $gameFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $gameName = $_POST["nameOfGame"];
    $query = "INSERT INTO `beoordelingen`.`beoordeling` (`ID`, `file`, `Spel`) VALUES (NULL, '{$target_file}', '{$gameName}')";

    //check if file exists
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $check = $_FILES["gameToUpload"]["tmp_name"];
        if (file_exists($target_file)) {
            echo "This game is already in the folder.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }

        if ($gameFileType != "swf") {
            echo "Sorry, only .swf is allowed for this page.";
        }

        if ($uploadOk = 0) {
            echo "Sorry, your file wasn't uploaded.";
        }

    else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["gameToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            echo "The file " . basename($_FILES["gameToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
            //$conn->query($query);
        }
        else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading the file.";
        }
      }
    }

?>
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select game (*.swf) to upload and add to master.php:
    <input type="file" name="gameToUpload" id="gameToUpload">
    <input type="text" name="nameOfGame" id="nameOfGame">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Game" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you echo echo `$gameFileType` ? I'm curious to see whether its `.swf` or `swf`

Answer (score 0):

May be you want to upload file that is big than `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in your `php.ini`.

Comment: you could make it as a comment

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The file I was trying to upload was only 3,54 mb large, so that wouldn't be an issue right ? The max post file size is set to 8 M.

Comment: By default limit is 2mb. Look at your php.ini

Comment: I set upload_max_filesize = 20M and post_max_size 8M. Still, doesn't let me upload. It also won't give me any error's just a blank page (if I remove the "echo 'Sorry,").

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake on your php code in

```
if ($uploadOk = 0) {
  echo "Sorry, your file wasn't uploaded.";
}
```

Change `$uploadOk = 0` to `$uploadOk != 0` or to `$uploadOk == 0`

Comment: And may be you must write $uploadOk = 0 after echo "Sorry, only .swf is allowed for this page." too.

Comment: Why would this be a mistake in your opinion ? I think it is supposed to be this way, because at this line I check if there were any problems before that line that changed this uploadOk to a zero, and then when it is zero it doesn't try to upload any further. But correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: In this way you must use "==" operation not "=". I have changed my answer.